# MSO read-only banner conflicting with MSO/MSE split banner

Tags: bug, mso-mse-split, read-only

When MSO goes into read-only, the notification banner(s) are stepping on each other's toes:

> [image: This site is currently in read-only mode: Well, look what we have here...]

Compared to the read-only banner on SO, which is just lovely all by itself:

> [image: SO Readonly]

Is this is most minor bug report ever? Perhaps. But at least it's not a pluralization bug.

Comment: That... How does that even happen. Just how.

Comment: Race condition for writing to the banner? `String.IndexOf('W')`? I dunno. I didn't think to do a view-source on the banner, which might have yielded some more info.

Comment: @michaelb958: I suspect there's a single "custom banner text" variable that is used for both read-only banners and other banners, with "This site is currently in read-only mode:" prepended to it when the site is in read-only mode. It kind of makes sense, if you assume that a typical banner will read something like "We're fixing some stuff tonight; expect random breakage until 04:00 UTC."

Comment: @IlmariKaronen That actually makes a surprising amount of sense.

Comment: Related bug report on MSO: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/305269/theres-a-lot-of-information-in-that-offline-message-now